# React Router Vite Module Federation Component Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite, webpack-module-federation

I have a component in a react project that is being exposed in my module federation config

```
    function Page(props: { routes: Route[] }) {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path='/*'
                    element={<Layout routes={props.routes} />}
                >
                    {props.routes.map((route) => (
                        <Route
                            key={route.key}
                            path={route.path}
                            element={route.component && <route.component />}
                        >
                            {route.children.length > 0 &&
                                route.children.map((childRoute) => (
                                    <Route
                                        key={childRoute.key}
                                        path={childRoute.path}
                                        element={
                                            childRoute.component && (
                                                <childRoute.component />
                                            )
                                        }
                                    />
                                ))}
                        </Route>
                    ))}
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is setting up the routes and a nav menu in Layout from a routes array

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
    //Section 1
    {
        key: 'section1',
        title: 'Section 1',
        path: 'sectionone',
        component: Outlet,
        icon: WorkIcon,
        children: [
            {
                key: 'page1',
                title: 'Page 1',
                path: 'pageone',
                component: PageOne,
                icon: undefined,
                children: [],
                visible: true,
            },
            {
                key: 'page2',
                title: 'Page 2',
                path: 'pagetwo',
                component: PageTwo,
                icon: undefined,
                children: [],
                visible: true,
            },
        ],
        visible: true,
    },
    //Section 2
    {
        key: 'section2',
        title: 'Section 2',
        path: 'sectiontwo',
        component: Outlet,
        icon: WorkIcon,
        children: [
            {
                key: 'page3',
                title: 'Page 3',
                path: 'pagethree',
                component: PageThree,
                icon: undefined,
                children: [],
                visible: true,
            },
            {
                key: 'page4',
                title: 'Page 4',
                path: 'pagefour',
                component: PageFour,
                icon: undefined,
                children: [],
                visible: true,
            },
        ],
        visible: true,
    },
]
```

When I pull the Page component and routes array into my host application with module federation

```
import { routes } from 'core/routes';
const Page = lazy(() => import('core/Page'));

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ErrorBoundary fallback={<Error />}>
            <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                <Page routes={routes} />
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

It all works correctly and the pages render correctly, but when I try to pull the Page into another application but instead of pulling in the routes from the core/App I use a custom routes array in that app.

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
    //New
    {
        key: 'new',
        title: 'New',
        path: 'new',
        component: Outlet,
        icon: PeopleAltIcon,
        children: [
            {
                key: 'dashboard',
                title: 'Dashboard',
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardScreen,
                icon: undefined,
                children: [],
                visible: true,
            },
            {
                key: 'view',
                title: 'View',
                path: 'view',
                component: ViewScreen,
                icon: undefined,
                children: [],
                visible: true,
            },
        ],
        visible: true,
    },
];

import { routes } from './routes/routes';
const Page = lazy(() => import('core/Page'));

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ErrorBoundary fallback={<div>Something went wrong</div>}>
            <Suspense fallback={'loading...'}>
                <Page routes={routes} />
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This doesnt render the screen component at all.

The Layout component contains the Outlet

```
return (
        <>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Breadcrumb open={open} />
                <Menu
                    routes={props.routes}
                    toggleFunc={toggleDrawer}
                    open={open}
                />
                <Box
                    component='main'
                    sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 2 }}
                >
                    <Outlet />
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
```

Can anyone help as to why these screen components do not render, as it seems like the setup is the same as my host application, just with a different routes array being passed in. The menu and routes/navigation seems to setup correctly as I can click the menu items and the route will change, its just that the component associated with the route is not rendered